# Foreign key reference to junction table create issue

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables that have a junction table in between due to fact that there is many to many relationship between. How do I make a foreign key reference from one of the tables to the junction table to obtain a specific ID(the primary key ID of the opposite table), the ID is part of the primary key of the junction table that is made up of two foreign keys of the two tables. I made a foreign key reference straight to the junction table but its throwing an error "The number of columns in the referencing column list for foreign key does not match those of the primary key in the referenced table" when launching the CREATE query for the tables. What should I do to successfully make a foreign key reference to junction table?

Comment: You have it backwards.  The junction/mapping table contains the foreign key references to each of the related tables.   `t1; t2; t1_t2 ( reference to t1, reference to t2 );`  t1 and t2 do not (normally) have direct references to each other or to the mapping table.  That's the purpose of the mapping table, to link t1 and t2 together.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The *many* side of both relationships will be at the junction table eg (written in SQL)

```
create table t1 (
  id int primary key
) ;

create table t2 (
  id int primary key
) ;

create table junction (
  t1id int references t1( id ) not null
, t2id int references t2( id ) not null
) ;

-- PK: 2 columns
alter table junction
add constraint pkey_j primary key( t1id, t2id ) ;
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ee520f73df20205e1e8d4fb26f9a1c1).